# Database agnostic table/view export software?

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle, components

*Trying to search for a more elegant/overall solution to our common/basic data export tasks*

I am convinced that there must be software out there that allows me to:

- Define and persist a "setup" (definition of file format, delimiters, encoding, column names etc) from a GUI
- Run on a schedule/from command line
- Work on both Oracle and MSSql

However, I haven't found it yet... any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The search ended in using products from http://sqlmanager.net.

They have products that covers the described needs, except that there are separate products for i.e. MSSQL and Oracle

Answer (score 0):

what about using groovy to export the data to xml files.

see http://groovy.codehaus.org/Convert+SQL+Result+To+XML

for the gui thing, [Oracle's SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/sql_developer/index.html) can connect to Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server, MS Access and Sybase